# no password for keyring

Tags: login, password, gnome-keyring

I do not know the keyring password for my Ubuntu. It seems someone must have tried to put in a password before, and no one knows what they tried , so now i can not get updates or use the terminal. I am a complete newbie to ubuntu and not sure how to get what version I have but maybe 14? 1) how do i find out? I had asked this question before and saw an answer to a similar question and have tried to use apt daemon and maybe got downloaded but unable to run due to keyring no password. so, is there a way to get a new keyring so i can make the password or what should i do? Please help since google and firefox are saying they will not run much longer without updating.. Please help with keyring. thank you!

Comment: First, try using the login password; that's the default keyring password until someone changes it. If that fails, open a terminal and run `lsb_release -a` and copy the result of the line which begins with Description. If that fails, click on System Settings, then Details, and look under the Ubuntu logo. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckingYourUbuntuVersion Please copy the result and paste it into your original question. Please click [edit] to add it into your question; please do not use Add Comment, but use [edit] instead.